# Excel macro stopped copying folders. Getting error that path cannot be found?

Tags: excel, vba, path, filesystemobject

I have been troubleshooting for a few hours what should be a simple bit of code.
I have a sub (CopyPasteTemplate) that is called from another sub on a userform within Excel.  It is designed to  check for a local folder (fromFolder) and copy the folders contained within to another folder (toFolder) on the same drive. I have run it hundreds of times with no problems until today.  I  did add a bit of code today to the userform, but did not modify the sub in question...at least not intentionally. Two variables are passed to the sub, but I verified they are being passed correctly.  I inserted a bit of troubleshooting code to see if the file paths are being stored correctly.  See below.

```
Private Sub CopyPasteTemplate(path As String, iPos As String)
   '--------------------
   'Copies folders from "0_Template Job Folder" ("fromFolder") to project folder ("toFolder") being created
   '--------------------
    Dim FSO
    Dim sFolder As String
    Dim fromFolder As String
    Dim toFolder As String
                
    sFolder = "0_Project Folder Template" 'This is the folder name with the contents you want to copy
                
    fromFolder = Left(LocalFullName(ActiveWorkbook.FullName), iPos) & sFolder & "\*" 'Location of folder(s) you want to copy"
                
    toFolder = path 'Change to match the destination folder path
                
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 'Create Object
            
'-------------this section created to determine which path cannot be found----------------------
    Debug.Print "fromFolder->" & fromFolder
    Debug.Print "toFolder->" & toFolder
    
    If FSO.FolderExists(fromFolder) = False Then
            Debug.Print "fromFolder found->" & fromFolder
    Else
            Debug.Print "fromFolder found->" & "not found"
    End If
    
    If FSO.FolderExists(toFolder) = False Then
            Debug.Print "toFolder found->" & toFolder
    Else
            Debug.Print "toFolder found->" & "not found"
    End If
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            
    If Not FSO.FolderExists(Left(LocalFullName(ActiveWorkbook.FullName), iPos) & sFolder) Then 'Checking If File Is Located in the Source Folder
         MsgBox "Specified Folder Not Found", vbInformation, "Not Found"
    Else
         FSO.CopyFolder (fromFolder), toFolder, True
         MsgBox "Specified Folder Copied Successfully", vbInformation, "Done!"
    End If
            
End Sub
```

As you can see by the debug printout the file path for the toFolder and fromFolder are correct, but FSO.FolderExists cannot find the toFolder path.

[image]

What am I missing?  Is there anything aside from modifying the code that could have changed?  Frankly I am stumped.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say

```
If FSO.FolderExists(fromFolder) = False Then
    Debug.Print "fromFolder found->" & fromFolder
'…
```

that means: *"If the folder does NOT exist"* then print that you found it. But it has to be the other way around. If it exists then print it. So you need to check for `True` not `False`.

```
If FSO.FolderExists(fromFolder) = True Then
    Debug.Print "fromFolder found->" & fromFolder
Else
    Debug.Print "fromFolder found->" & "not found"
End If

If FSO.FolderExists(toFolder) = True Then
    Debug.Print "toFolder found->" & toFolder
Else
    Debug.Print "toFolder found->" & "not found"
End If
```

So that means that actually your `toFolder` was found but your `fromFolder` was not found. And that is because it contains `\*` in the end. Remove that and it will be found too.

---

#### Investigations

I created 2 folders in `C:\Temp\test folder`:

- `"C:\Temp\test folder\1"` (containing some data to copy)
- `"C:\Temp\test folder\2 -"` (empty destination, the path ends right after the dash!)

Then I set up the following test

```
Sub test()
    Dim FSO As Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    Dim FromFolder As String
    FromFolder = "c:\temp\test folder\1"
    
    Dim ToFolder As String
    ToFolder = "c:\temp\test folder\2 -   "  'the path has trailing spaces after the dash so it should not exist on the disk!
    
    Debug.Print "Found FromFolder:", FSO.FolderExists(FromFolder), """" & FromFolder & """"
    Debug.Print "Found ToFolder:  ", FSO.FolderExists(ToFolder), """" & ToFolder & """"
    
    FSO.CopyFolder FromFolder, ToFolder, True
End Sub
```

The outcome of this is

```
Found FromFolder:           Wahr          "c:\temp\test folder\1"
Found ToFolder:             Wahr          "c:\temp\test folder\2 -   "
```

So actually `FSO.FolderExists(ToFolder)` returns `True` even if this folder does actually not exist. Looks like it is ignoring the trailing spaces and finds `"c:\temp\test folder\2 -"` (without the spaces) that does exist!

At the same time `FSO.CopyFolder FromFolder, ToFolder, True` fails with *"Path not found"*. Looks like it does **not** ignore the trailing spaces!

So I recommend to do the following `ToFolder = Trim(ToFolder)` to trim off any spaces at the end or beginning of the path. Or in your code `toFolder = Trim(path)`.

Comment: You are correct.  Not sure how I missed that one.

Comment: I made some corrections to the part of the code that checks for the folders and FSO.FolderExists is able to find both folders, but now I am more confused.  If both folders can be found then why does FSO.CopyFolder return "path not found" run time error.  It has been running before with no issues.

Comment: @PressureMan Hard to say, I cannot reproduce your issue. Make sure there is no backslash in the end of the path. `c:\temp\fromfolder` works but `c:\temp\fromfolder\ ` does not work.

Comment: I narrowed down the problem to the **toFolder** variable.  If I define **toFolder** as the actual path in quotes (**toFolder = "C:\Users\..."**), the sub runs with no issues.  If I define **toFolder** as the passed variable (**toFolder = path**) is gives me the run time error.  What is odd is that if I do a **Debug.Print** for path and **"C:\Users\..."** directly after defining  **toFolder** (as a sanity check), the output in the window is identical.

Comment: @PressureMan I did some investigations. Have a look at my edit. Looks like trailing spaces cause the trouble and there is a bug in `FolderExists`.

Comment: "Lightbulb"...that is it.  I didn't realize I had put a space after the "-" when I defined `path`.  Thank you so much. You have been a huge help.